# Boundedness implying compactness

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous functions on a compact set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42465/continuous-functions-on-a-compact-set)

Let $K$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n > 1$. Why does it follows that if every continuous real-valued function defined on $K$ is bounded, then $K$ is compact?

Comment: One idea is to prove that $K$ is closed and bounded, and then invoke [Heine-Borel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem).

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think this is related to the extreme value theorem, which states that every continuous real-valued function defined on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded. Therefore, if there are no unbounded function, it'd be tempting to guess it's compact. There are some gaps to fill in here though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $K$ is not compact, then either it is not closed or it is not bounded. In either case, it is easy to construct a continuous unbounded real-valued function on $K$. If $K$ is not closed, take the reciprocal of the distance to a limit point. If $K$ is not bounded, take the modulus.

Comment: "If K is not closed, take the reciprocal of the distance to a limit point." - perhaps you can explicitly say that the limit point is *not in $K$*. Of course, it's clear that that's what you meant, since if we take a limit point in $K$, then the function is not even defined at that point, and hence cannot be continuous in $K$.