# A continuous function on $S^1$- unit circle .

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

$$S^1=\{z\in \mathbb C : |z|=1\}$$  be the unit circle. Then which of the following  is  **false** $?$

Any **continuous** function  from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R$ is

A. bounded

B. uniformly continuous.

C. has image containing a non empty open subset of $\mathbb R.$

D. has a point $z\in S^1$  such that  $f(z)=f(-z)$

Since $S^1$ is compact any continuous function would be bounded  or  uniformly  continuous so  $A$  and $B$  are  correct.

For $C$, the  constant  function  does not have any open interval in its image. Thus, $C$ is **the**  **false** statement.

That leaves $D$ to be correct. How can I prove the existence of a point $z$ having properties  like  said  in $D$?

Comment: Think about the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You can find related results with the Borsuk-Ulam theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem

Answer (score 14):

You prove D by the intermediate value theorem, used on the function
$$
g(z)=f(z)-f(-z)
$$
Pick a $z_0\in S^1$, and evaluate $g$ there. If you get $0$, then you're done. If not, then $g(z_0)=-g(-z_0)$, so $g$ changes sign. That means there must be a zero somewhere, and that somewhere is the $z$ you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

$S^1$ is compact hence every continuous function on it is [bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42465/continuous-functions-on-a-compact-set) and [uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous). Certainly, the image of a constant function consists of one point only. As for the last one, have you heard about the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score -1):

$D$ is true.
Proof:

Define the function $g:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$.
Note that $g(S^1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is convex, then $\forall x\in S^1,(\frac{1}{2}g(x)+\frac{1}{2}g(-x))\in g(S^1).$ Now $(\frac{1}{2}g(x)+\frac{1}{2}g(-x))=0\in S^1$, then exist $ y\in S^1 \mid g(y)= 0$.