# Can I slightly modify a convex function so that it has a unique minimum point and the difference is uniformly bounded?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Consider a convex function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is convex compact. Such convex function may have multiple minimizers, i.e., $\arg \min\limits_{u \in U}f$ has more than one element.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, I'd like to find a convex function $g: U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert \lvert f - g\rvert \rvert_{\infty} < \epsilon$ and $g$ has a unique minimizer.

My insight is, choose an arbitrary minimizer $u^{*}$ of the function $f$, and let $z$ be the corresponding point $(u^{*}, \min\limits_{u \in U}f(u) - \delta)$ with positive constant $\delta > 0$.

And consider the convex hull of the epigraph of $f$ and $z$, namely, $Z$. There (probably) exists a $\delta > 0$ such that the function $g$ corresponding to the epigraph $Z$ will satisfy the requirement. Is there something like this, or, is my insight correct and provable?

Comment: Add to it some strictly convex continuous function on $U$ multiplied by some number $\varepsilon$. [The sum is strictly convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325952/152568), hence [has a unique minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function). The difference is uniformly bounded by the [boundedness theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42465/152568), and can be made arbitrarily small using $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ah, you're right! It is a very straightforward and easy solution... Why couldn't I come up with this? Thank you!
The answer is enough, but can I ask you a further question? "How can I properly construct such a strictly convex continuous function in general?" I mean, I know we can find such a function, but I'm not sure how I can "construct" it in general.

Comment: The standard choice is the Euclidean square-norm, the sum of the squares of coordinates, see [convex regularization](https://kenndanielso.github.io/mlrefined/blog_posts/13_Multilayer_perceptrons/13_5_regularization.html).

Comment: Ok, I think this should be fine: for all elements in $\partial U$, give a value $0$. Also, pick an element $v$ from $\arg \min_{u \in U} f$, and give a value $-\epsilon$. And make a convex hull of $\{(u, 0): u \in \partial U\} \cup \{(v, -\epsilon)\}$, and retrieve a corresponding function $g$ by regarding the convex hull as the epigraph.

Comment: Just take $g(u)=f(u)+\epsilon \|u-u^*\|^2$ where $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small ($U$ is compact) and $u^*$ is a minimiser.

Comment: I feel like I'm stupid... yeah, your answer is much easy and clear!